# Add to Media Inserter Categories

Tags: block-editor, media

As of Wordpress 6.2, Openverse was integrated into wordpress and it is available under the Media Tab of the Inserter.

I want to develop a plugin that integrates another stock image service into the Media Inserter Tab as well, but browsing through the documentation and the source code, there doesn't seem to be any hooks I can put it in.

From what I know, the categories are registered under the `inserterMediaCategories` const in editor js. Is there a way I can add to it in a plugin?

[image]